# What does "country" shows for WiFi router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

When I scan WiFi with Wireless Diagnostics tool on Mac OS X (Window -> Utilities -> Scan WiFi), it shows a lot of information about WiFi routers around me.

I realize that some routers have "JP" in their country fields even though I am in US and the most routers shows "US" in that field.

Is there anybody can tell why some routers have "JP" and what is the meaning of "country" field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the so-called "Regulatory Domain" the router is set to. It defines which channels can be used, power limits for transmitting etc.

If a network does not indicate its setting, the access point is either set to "International" (using limits legal all over the world) or does not support broadcasting this information.